# Different meanings for "endurance"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I found similar translations for "endurance" and don't know how to distinguish them:

1. [[耐久]{たいきゅう}](http://takoboto.jp/?w=1410360)
2. [[忍耐]{にんたい}](http://takoboto.jp/?w=1467500)
3. [[我慢]{がまん}](http://takoboto.jp/?w=1196970)

**What are the patterns to distinguish one from another and to generally find out which I should choose?**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

耐久 the nature of a thing to be able to withstand external forces for an extended period. Being of inherently strong composition. Permanence. Durability. Hardiness.

我慢 Holding in an impulse and carrying on despite the impulse. Implies ‘carrying on’ despite a burden or ‘sucking it up’ despite hardship, by virtue of one’s willpower. Does not necessarily imply longevity.

忍耐 Being calmly patient. Waiting is an essential part of this usage. Implies longevity.

Your pre-edit post showed that you used Takaboto.jp. Whether you use this or another site try to avail yourself of the example sentences provided in order to increase your understanding of the nuances and usages.

Comment: thank you very much! But how do you know? they all mean endurance, but their specific meaning differs.

Comment: 耐久 should be understood from the main answer (mainly durability of objects). 我慢 is used to indicate enduring something without any thought and without a plan for the future (toleration). 忍耐 is used to indicate enduring something in order to accomplish a cause achieve a goal (patience). Again, reading many examples of how it is used in context will be the most help.

Answer (score 2):

user27280 has done a good job explaining the terms you listed, but I just want to add that if you are looking for "endurance" in the sports and athletics sense of the word, it's typically `体力` or `持久力`.

`体力` is used for athletic ability fairly broadly, but this definitely encompasses endurance and someone who wears out quickly can be described as lacking `体力`.

`持久力` is the more technical/specific term for endurance. For example, "endurance training" is `持久力トレーニング`.

Comment: I should have considered that interpretation. Thanks for the follow-up.